# Decoding URL encoded UTF-8 strings in VBScript

Tags: utf-8, vbscript, urldecode

I need to URL decode a string in a VBScript. The string may contain Unicode characters which are encoded as multiple bytes as per UTF-8. So for example "Paris%20%E2%86%92%20Z%C3%BCrich" would decode to "Paris → Zürich".

To do the job, I'm using a piece of code that looks like this:

```
Function URLDecode(str)
    set list = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    strLen = Len(str)
    for i = 1 to strLen
        sT = mid(str, i, 1)
        if sT = "%" then
            if i + 2 <= strLen then
                list.Add cbyte("&H" & mid(str, i + 1, 2))
                i = i + 2
            end if
        else
            list.Add asc(sT)
        end if
    next
    depth = 0
    for each by in list.ToArray()
        if by and &h80 then
            if (by and &h40) = 0 then
                if depth = 0 then Err.Raise 5
                val = val * 2 ^ 6 + (by and &h3f)
                depth = depth - 1
                if depth = 0 then
                    sR = sR & chrw(val)
                    val = 0
                end if
            elseif (by and &h20) = 0 then
                if depth > 0 then Err.Raise 5
                val = by and &h1f
                depth = 1
            elseif (by and &h10) = 0 then
                if depth > 0 then Err.Raise 5
                val = by and &h0f
                depth = 2
            else
                Err.Raise 5
            end if
        else
            if depth > 0 then Err.Raise 5
            sR = sR & chrw(by)
        end if
    next
    if depth > 0 then Err.Raise 5
    URLDecode = sR
End Function
```

This seems to be working well, but it looks exaggeratedly complex to me. In times of HTML5 and web standards, there must be a simpler way to get this done without a bunch of hand-made loops and conditions. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I want to show three methods for three vary environments. All of these methods requires JScript's `encodeURIComponent` and `decodeURIComponent` functions.

**1. In ASP, using server-side JavaScript is one of most appropriate solutions :**

```js
<script language="javascript" runat="server">
URL = {
    encode : function(s){return encodeURIComponent(s).replace(/'/g,"%27").replace(/"/g,"%22")},
    decode : function(s){return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(/\+/g,  " "))}
}
</script>
<%
Response.Write URL.decode("Paris%20%E2%86%92%20Z%C3%BCrich")
Response.Write URL.encode("Paris → Zürich")
%>
```

**2. 32-Bit only (*due to MSScriptControl.ScriptControl is 32-bit only component*) in any other WSH :**

```vb
Dim JSEngine
Set JSEngine = CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")
    JSEngine.Language = "JScript"

Function UrlEncode(s)
    UrlEncode = JSEngine.CodeObject.encodeURIComponent(s)
    UrlEncode = Replace(UrlEncode, "'", "%27")
    UrlEncode = Replace(UrlEncode, """", "%22")
End Function

Function UrlDecode(s)
    UrlDecode = Replace(s, "+", " ")
    UrlDecode = JSEngine.CodeObject.decodeURIComponent(UrlDecode)
End Function

WScript.Echo UrlDecode("Paris%20%E2%86%92%20Z%C3%BCrich")
WScript.Echo UrlEncode("Paris → Zürich")
```

**3. With 64-bit support in any other WSH using a WSC:**

**urlencdec.wsc** (created by using [WSC Wizard](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11914))

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<component>
<?component error="true" debug="true"?>
    <registration
        description="Url Encode / Decode Helper"
        progid="JSEngine.Url"
        version="1.0"
        classid="{80246bcc-45d4-4e92-95dc-4fd9a93d8529}"
    />
    <public>
        <method name="encode">
            <PARAMETER name="s"/>
        </method>
        <method name="decode">
            <PARAMETER name="s"/>
        </method>
    </public>
    <script language="JScript">
    <![CDATA[
        var description = new UrlEncodeDecodeHelper;

        function UrlEncodeDecodeHelper() {

            this.encode = encode;
            this.decode = decode;
        }

        function encode(s) {
            return encodeURIComponent(s).replace(/'/g,"%27").replace(/"/g,"%22");
        }

        function decode(s) {
            return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(/\+/g,  " "));
        }
    ]]>
    </script>
</component>
```

**and vbs code :**

```vb
Dim JSEngine
Set JSEngine = GetObject("Script:C:\urlencdec.wsc")

WScript.Echo JSEngine.decode("Paris%20%E2%86%92%20Z%C3%BCrich")
WScript.Echo JSEngine.encode("Paris → Zürich")
```

Comment: @ft1 I made a fix, bear in mind that if you used second solution.

Comment: Wow, had no idea you could mix JavaScript and VB like that. Mind = blown. This opens up a whole new world when stuck in classic ASP!

Comment: Note that `Request.Querystring()` will automatically decode escaped characters for you, but this only helps if you're getting the encoded string via the querystring.

Comment: @Martha true. BTW that implicit url decoding also applies to `Request.Form` and `Request.Cookies`.

Comment: Fantastic solution.

Answer (score 7):

Pure vbs classic asp of **URLDecode** function, with utf-8 support.

```
<%
Function RegExTest(str,patrn)
    Dim regEx
    Set regEx = New RegExp
    regEx.IgnoreCase = True
    regEx.Pattern = patrn
    RegExTest = regEx.Test(str)
End Function

Function URLDecode(sStr)
    Dim str,code,a0
    str=""
    code=sStr
    code=Replace(code,"+"," ")
    While len(code)>0
        If InStr(code,"%")>0 Then
            str = str & Mid(code,1,InStr(code,"%")-1)
            code = Mid(code,InStr(code,"%"))
            a0 = UCase(Mid(code,2,1))
            If a0="U" And RegExTest(code,"^%u[0-9A-F]{4}") Then
                str = str & ChrW((Int("&H" & Mid(code,3,4))))
                code = Mid(code,7)
            ElseIf a0="E" And RegExTest(code,"^(%[0-9A-F]{2}){3}") Then
                str = str & ChrW((Int("&H" & Mid(code,2,2)) And 15) * 4096 + (Int("&H" & Mid(code,5,2)) And 63) * 64 + (Int("&H" & Mid(code,8,2)) And 63))
                code = Mid(code,10)
            ElseIf a0>="C" And a0<="D" And RegExTest(code,"^(%[0-9A-F]{2}){2}") Then
                str = str & ChrW((Int("&H" & Mid(code,2,2)) And 3) * 64 + (Int("&H" & Mid(code,5,2)) And 63))
                code = Mid(code,7)
            ElseIf (a0<="B" Or a0="F") And RegExTest(code,"^%[0-9A-F]{2}") Then
                str = str & Chr(Int("&H" & Mid(code,2,2)))
                code = Mid(code,4)
            Else
                str = str & "%"
                code = Mid(code,2)
            End If
        Else
            str = str & code
            code = ""
        End If
    Wend
    URLDecode = str
End Function


Response.Write URLDecode("Paris%20%E2%86%92%20Z%C3%BCrich") 'Paris → Zürich
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

This vbscript code is inspired by @kul-Tigin solution in order to generate the `urlencdec.wsc` in Application Data folder and use it with the same vbscript file :

```
'Question : Decoding URL encoded UTF-8 strings in VBScript
'URL : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17880395/decoding-url-encoded-utf-8-strings-in-vbscript?answertab=active#tab-top

Option Explicit
Dim JSEngine,ws,WSC
Set ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WSC = ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%AppData%\urlencdec.wsc")
Call Create_URL_ENC_DEC_Component(WSC)
Set JSEngine = GetObject("Script:"& WSC)

WScript.Echo JSEngine.decode("%D9%81%D9%8A%D9%84%D9%85-21Bridges-2019-%D9%85%D8%AA%D8%B1%D8%AC%D9%85")
WScript.Echo JSEngine.encode("Paris → Zürich")


Sub Create_URL_ENC_DEC_Component(WSC)
Dim fso,File
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set File = fso.OpenTextFile(WSC,2,True)
File.WriteLine "<?xml version=""1.0""?>"
File.WriteLine "<component>"
File.WriteLine "<?component error=""true"" debug=""true""?>"
File.WriteLine     "<registration"
File.WriteLine         "description=""Url Encode / Decode Helper"""
File.WriteLine         "progid=""JSEngine.Url"""
File.WriteLine         "version=""1.0"""
File.WriteLine         "classid=""{80246bcc-45d4-4e92-95dc-4fd9a93d8529}"""
File.WriteLine     "/>"
File.WriteLine    "<public>"
File.WriteLine         "<method name=""encode"">"
File.WriteLine             "<PARAMETER name=""s""/>"
File.WriteLine         "</method>"
File.WriteLine         "<method name=""decode"">"
File.WriteLine             "<PARAMETER name=""s""/>"
File.WriteLine         "</method>"
File.WriteLine     "</public>"
File.WriteLine     "<script language=""JScript"">"
File.WriteLine     "<![CDATA["
File.WriteLine         "var description = new UrlEncodeDecodeHelper;"
File.WriteLine         "function UrlEncodeDecodeHelper() {"
File.WriteLine             "this.encode = encode;"
File.WriteLine             "this.decode = decode;"
File.WriteLine         "}"
File.WriteLine         "function encode(s) {"
File.WriteLine            "return encodeURIComponent(s).replace(/'/g,""%27"").replace(/""/g,""%22"");"
File.WriteLine         "}"
File.WriteLine         "function decode(s) {"
File.WriteLine             "return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(/\+/g,  "" ""));"
File.WriteLine         "}"
File.WriteLine     "]]>"
File.WriteLine     "</script>"
File.WriteLine "</component>"
End Sub
```

Comment: There is only one thing I cannot understand. Why did you create the file in the %AppData% folder and not in %temp%

Answer (score 0):

The best way of encoding a URL using VBS is to use encodeURIComponent() javascript function!! The ScriptControl component allows you to run js code from a VBS environment.

Here's my URLEncode function, which works exactly the same as the js function (in fact, it calls it!!):

```
Function URLEncode(str)
    Dim encodedUrl
    Set sc = CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")
    sc.Language = "JScript"
    sc.AddCode "var s = """ & str & """;"
    sc.AddCode "function myEncode(s){return encodeURIComponent(s);}"
    encodedUrl = sc.Eval("myEncode(s);")
    Set sc = Nothing
    URLEncode = encodedUrl
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

My code (without creating temporary files)

Encode URI

```
Option Explicit
Const WshRunning = 0,WshFailed = 1:Dim cmd,text,arr,i
If WScript.Arguments.Count()=0 Then 
    text=CreateObject("HTMLFile").parentWindow.clipboardData.GetData("text")    
Else
    ReDim arr(WScript.Arguments.Count-1)
    For i=0 To WScript.Arguments.Count-1:arr(i)=WScript.Arguments(i):Next
    text=Join(arr)
End if
if IsNull(text) Then 
    WScript.Echo "No data to execute.."
else
    text=Replace(text,"""","\%22")
    text=Replace(text,"'","\%27")
    cmd="for /f ""usebackq"" %i in " & _
    "(`mshta ""javascript:Code(close(new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).Write(" & _
    "encodeURIComponent('" & text & "')" & _
    ")));""`) do set e=%i&set e=!e:'=%27!&set e=!e:(=%28!&set e=!e:)=%29!&echo !e!"
    Dim shell : Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim exec : Set exec = shell.Exec("cmd /v /c " & cmd)
    While exec.Status = WshRunning
        WScript.Sleep 50
    Wend
    Dim output
    Dim err
    If exec.ExitCode = WshFailed Then
        err = exec.StdErr.ReadAll
    Else
        output = Split(exec.StdOut.ReadAll,Chr(10))
    End If
    If err="" Then
        WScript.Echo output(2)
    Else
        WScript.Echo "Error=" & err
    End If
End if
```

Decode URI

```
Option Explicit
Dim Kod
If WScript.Arguments.Count()=0 Then 
    Kod=CreateObject("HTMLFile").parentWindow.clipboardData.GetData("text") 
Else
    Kod=WScript.Arguments(0)
End if
if IsNull(Kod) Then 
    WScript.Echo "No data to execute.."
Else
    Dim chunk,Recoded,k1,k2,k3,i:i=0:Dim arr:arr=Split(Kod,"%")
    Do While i <= UBound(arr)
        if i<>0 Then
            chunk = Left(arr(i),2)      
            If "&H"&Left(chunk,2)>=128 then
                arr(i)="":i=i+1:chunk = chunk & Left(arr(i),2)
                If "&H"&Left(chunk,2)<224 then 
                    k1=Cint("&H"&Left(chunk,2)) mod 32
                    k2 = Cint("&H"&Mid(chunk,3,2)) mod 64
                    Recoded=ChrW( k2 + k1 * 64 )
                Else
                    arr(i)="":i=i+1:chunk = chunk & Left(arr(i),4)
                    k1=Cint("&H"&Left(chunk,2)) mod 16
                    k2 = Cint("&H"&Mid(chunk,3,2)) mod 32
                    k3 = Cint("&H"&Mid(chunk,5,2)) mod 64
                    Recoded=ChrW( k3 + ( k2 + k1 * 64 ) * 64 )
                End if
            Else Recoded=Chr("&H"&chunk)
            End If
            arr(i)=Recoded & Mid(arr(i),3)
        end if:i=i+1
    loop
    Kod=Join(arr,""):WScript.Echo Kod
End if
```